# Having trouble with the sort method

Tags: ruby, sorting

I am building a histogram based on of the amount of words in a text file. I have an array of hashes whose keys are the words and the values are the amount of times the word appears per line. I need to use the `sort` method on this array of hashes to sort the values in order of the most occurring word to the least. This is what my sort line looks like:

```
twoOfArray.sort { |k, v| v <=> k }
twoOfArray.each { |key, value| puts "#{key} occurs #{value} times" "\n"}
```

Full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/WufPzpwK). If I use the `sort!` method, I get an undefined method error. Does anyone know why?

Comment: `sort` takes two arguments in the block: each is of the original type and your block tells `sort` how to compare them. So it should be, `twoOfArray.sort { |a1, a2| # do something here to compare hash a1 with hash a2 }`. Judging from your `each` statement, it looks like `twoOfArray` is itself a hash, not an array of hashes as you indicated? So you're trying to apply `sort` to a Hash which is not defined.

Comment: Please edit to include the "full code" in your question.  Questions should be able to survive link breakage.

Comment: @lurker So my 'twoOfArray' is actually just a hash? So if its just a hash then what can I do to it to sort it then?

Comment: It would appear that Ruby will internally convert the hash into an array of small 2-element arrays when applying `sort`, and the `sort` method would need to be applied accordingly, per the answer given by @StewartNelson. Remember, though, if you convert it back to a hash, it's order isn't guaranteed. A hash is not an ordered data type in the way that an array is.

Comment: what does `bag.select` return? i thought select only takes 1 argument, not `k` and `v`

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your data structure (an array of hashes) into just one large hash. If you want to sort the words, there's no reason to have them in separate hashes.

Then, if your hash is something like `{'the' => 5, 'and' => 23, 'beer' => 2}` you can sort via:

```
> h = {'the' => 5, 'and' => 23, 'beer' => 2}
> a = h.sort {|a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] } # sort converts a hash into an array of arrays.
> a
#=> [['and', 23], ['the', 5], ['beer', 2]]
```